# How to upgrade Windows Vista to Windows 8 pro?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

I am currently using the Windows Vista service pack 2. I want it to upgrade it to Windows 8. Can any one have suggestion for how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

[Run the Upgrade tool and buy the license](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/buy) with credit card or Paypal and download the required data and upgrade.

Comment: so i don't need it to upgrade to windows 7 first?

Comment: No you needn't. You can do a direct upgrade. Make sure to read the instructions carefully to know what will be carried over in the upgrade and what won't

Comment: you only need to upgrade to Win7 if you don't want to reinstall all desktop applications. Vista to Win8 upgrade only migrate data and settings.